# Why backspace '\b' does not work in C++?

Tags: c++

I have created a loop and because it is long, I wanted to see the progress. So, I have added some backspace characters for printing the percentage of the loop on the same line:

```
std::size_t photoCntr = 0;
for (std::vector< VerifObj >::const_iterator itVOV = verifObjVector.begin(); itVOV != verifObjVector.end(); itVOV++)
{
    // some operations

    std::cout << "\b\b\b\b" << std::setw(3) << static_cast< int >(100.f * ++photoCntr / verifObjVector.size()) << "%";
}
```

In the console it is not printing anything until the end of the loop and then it is printing `100%`. The loop takes long (some minutes). I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and g++11. Can it be some kind of optimization that do not print until the buffer is full? Any ideas of how to make it work?

Comment: Output to `std::cout` is *buffered*. Add a `<< std::flush` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the output buffer:

```
std::cout.flush();
```

You can also use this style:

```
std::cout << "Stuff" << std::flush;
```

---

Just to be thorough, this complete program prints an increasing progress in place:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
   for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
      std::cout << "\b\b\b\b" << std::setw(3) << i << '%' << std::flush;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
   }
   std::cout << "\b\b\b\b100%" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why is it printing: ` 0%0xa8  0%0xa8  0%0xa8  1%0xa85f48` ?

Comment: That would be because of problems elsewhere in your code. Are you printing a pointer where you wanted to print an int? Anyway; that is a different question, so please use the "Ask question"-button to ask it :)

Comment: Sorry, the problem was because I had a line before the loop that I have not inserted in the code: `std::cout << std::setw(3) << 0 << "%";`. After adding the `<< std::flush` at its end there was not hexa printing anymore.

Comment: Note that it's also easier to print `\r` (a carriage return without a newline) rather than a specific number of backslashes.